# Named Queries using Nest and Elastic Search

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-2.0

I'd like to name my queries that I send to my elastic search instance (version 2.3) so i can see the name in my log file.  I use a .net application which uses NEST.2.1.1 to interact with the elastic search index.  According to the ES documentation I should be able to use _name to give a name to my query but there's no method called that available, there is something called .Stats which claims to do the same thing but this just doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

All query descriptors have method to set name.

For example, range:

```
var response = client.Search<Product>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.Range(dr => dr.Name("_range").Field(f => f.Price1).LessThan(1)))
    );
```

which produces following query to ES:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "range" : {
            "price1" : {
                "_name" : "_range",
                "lt" : 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.